# npm installs modules into current directory, not only node_modules

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I tried to create new project and did like this.

```
> express newproject

> cd newproject

> ls
app.js          package.json    public/         routes/         views/

> npm install

// ...

> ls
app.js                  commander/              cookie-signature/       formidable/             methods/                node_modules/           public/                 routes/
buffer-crc32/           connect/                debug/                  fresh/                  mime/                   package.json            qs/                     send/
bytes/                  cookie/                 express/                jade/                   mkdirp/                 pause/                  range-parser/           views/
```

Why the files are downloaded into current directory? Is this a bug?

### Resolved

I resolved this issue by fixing ~/.npmrc.

```
- cache = .
+ cache = ~/.npm
```

It works!

Comment: you using the latest version of express?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of package.json?

Comment: And also – where did `package.json`, `public/`, `routes/` and `views/` go? Are you sure you're in the same directory as before?

Comment: Thank you very much. But finally, I've resolved this issue. It was because of "cache = ." in .npmrc. I changed it into "chace = ~/.npm" and it have got worked fine.

Comment: you should add an answer to the question instead of editing it with "Resolved"

Answer (score 1):

### Resolved

I resolved this issue by fixing ~/.npmrc.

```
- cache = .
+ cache = ~/.npm
```

It works!